# Execute python 3 code from c# forms application

Tags: c#, python, .net

As a school project  my class made a simple programing language in python 3. Now we made a simple ide in c# that should execute python script in a new console window. I was wondering what is most efficient way to do it. (I should execute it with parameters)

Comment: what did you try so far? please post your code

Comment: I tried to use IronPython and with ProcessStartInfo but IronPython was not working every time i tried and ProcessStartInfo would close automatically. Here's my project https://www.mediafire.com/?81ppkgl5fpel595

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ProcessStartInfo`

```
int parameter1 = 10;
int parameter2  = 5
Process p = new Process(); // create process to run the python program
p.StartInfo.FileName = "python.exe"; //Python.exe location
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; // ensures you can read stdout
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "c:\\src\\yourpythonscript.py "+parameter1 +" "+parameter2; // start the python program with two parameters
p.Start(); // start the process (the python program)
StreamReader s = p.StandardOutput;
String output = s.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(output);
p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: I tried this and consloe opens and closes without any output

Comment: I won't be able to access that until later today, but I have corrected the script so it doesn't parse the output. It works correctly for a `print "Hello World"` app.

Answer (score 0):

There is two way to run the python script:

1. One way is to run the python script is by running the **python.exe** file:

   Run the python.exe file using ProcessStartInfo and pass the python script on it.

> private void run_cmd(string cmd, string args) {
>
>  ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
>
> ```
>      start.FileName = "my/full/path/to/python.exe";
>      start.Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", cmd, args);
>      start.UseShellExecute = false;
>      start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
>      using(Process process = Process.Start(start))
>      {
>          using(StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
>          {
>              string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
>              Console.Write(result);
>          }
>      }  
> }
> ```

2. Another way is using **IronPython** and execute the python script file directly.

> using IronPython.Hosting;
>
> using Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting;
>
> ```
> private static void doPython()
> {
>     ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
>     engine.ExecuteFile(@"test.py");
> }
> ```